# Creating public URL for Skipper upload on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, skipper

I'm uploading my image to Amazon Web Service S3 using **Skipper.js**, but creating a public **URL** for the file uploaded hasn't been possible using **Skipper.js**. I don't want to use **Skipper-Disk** I want to upload to **S3** and be able to create a publicly accessible url to download the file. My code is below and that's all I've done

```
 imageUpload: function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req);
    req.file('avatar').upload({
        adapter: skipper,
        key: 'key',
        secret: 'secret',
        bucket: 'bucketName'
    }, function(err, fileUploaded){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.negotiate(err);
        }

        if (fileUploaded.length === 0) {
            return res.badRequest('No files uploaded');
        }

        var imageUrl = fileUploaded[0].extra.Location;
        var imageKy = fileUploaded[0].extra.Key;
        ImageUpload.create({urlLink: imageUrl, imageKey: imageKy}).then(function(urlAdded){
            if (urlAdded) {
                //return res.negotiate(err);
                //The linkAdded is the link the s3 provides to the image E.g https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/filename
                return res.json({linkAdded: urlAdded});
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err){
            return res.badRequest(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you did all the upload code right assuming at the top of the file you have:

```
var skipper = require('skipper-s3')
```

The actual fix has to do with S3 config. In the AWS S3 console, with your bucket selected you need to select properties -> permissions -> Edit Bucket Policy.

Add this code to make your bucket have public GET requests but replace "bucketName" in the Resource param with your bucket name:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So even if I add `header: { "x-amz-acl": "public-read-write" }` in the skipper config section - Do I need to change the bucket policy?